# C# - Directory Search not returning results for parent directory

Tags: c#

I have this file count function that is not returning results from my parent directory. It does return results of all sub directories. During my debugging I def see the parent directory being passed as my Directory.GetDirectories(sDir) but once it hits  Directory.GetFiles(d) it already changed to the sub directories. I am banging my head against a wall on this one. Clearly, it must be my foreach loop but I am not seeing it.

The file structure I am passing is:

C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Temp Logs

but it has three sub directories:

C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Temp Logs\sub1

C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Temp Logs\sub2

C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Temp Logs\sub3

Does anyone see my error?

```
     private static string fileCount(string sDir, string sfileType)
    {
        int count = 0;
        string extension;
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(d))
            {
                extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
                if (extension.ToUpper().Equals(sfileType.ToUpper()))
                {
                    TimeSpan fileAge = DateTime.Now - File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
                    if (fileAge.Days > int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["numberOfDays"]))
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't Directory.GetDirectories only return subdirectories of the argument?

Comment: What output number are you expecting and what are you actually getting?

Comment: As @Casey pointed out, Directory.GetDirectories doesn't return the parent directory https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx put an extra Directory.GetFiles for the parent directory outside the foreach

Comment: I would suggest refactoring such that all the code inside the outer "for each" is in a separate function instead.  Make that function take a directory as a parameter, and return a number of the count.  From there, simply pass the parent directory just before the "for each" loop  and then pass each sub directory inside the for each loop, and accumulate the results as you go.

Answer (score 1):

You need another loop for the parent directory but outside you current loop

```
foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(parent_path))
        {
            extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
            if (extension.ToUpper().Equals(sfileType.ToUpper()))
            {
                TimeSpan fileAge = DateTime.Now - File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
                if (fileAge.Days > int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["numberOfDays"]))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. That was so easy. I guess I misunderstood what my directory loops were doing.

Answer (score 0):

The array you use in the foreach only contains SubDirectories. Add the parent and your good to go!

```
private static string fileCount(string sDir, string sfileType)
{
    int count = 0;
    string extension;
    List<string> directoriesToCheck = Directory.GetDirectories(sDir).ToList();
    directoriesToCheck.Add(sDir);
    foreach (string d in directoriesToCheck)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(d))
        {
            extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file);
            if (extension.ToUpper().Equals(sfileType.ToUpper()))
            {
                TimeSpan fileAge = DateTime.Now - File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
                if (fileAge.Days > int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["numberOfDays"]))
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count.ToString();
}
```